# Can I run MQTT broker inside a Spring boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mosquitto, spring-integration-mqtt

Is it possible to have a mqqt broker like Mosquitto to run inside Spring boot application? Or any other mqqt broker? I found that eclipse paho library, which can be a client inside Spring boot app. I wonder if we have something similar for a mqqt broker?

Comment: What problem are you trying solve by wanting to do this?

Comment: @romkey I want to process the receiving mqtt messages and save to the database.  I can do this by by making the spring boot app as a mqtt client. But it would be nice if I can make the spring boot app as the broker itself. If my spring-boot app is a client, then I need to subscribe for all the topics as well.

Comment: I don't see any advantage to doing it the way you describe. You need to subscribe to whatever topics you want regardless of where the broker runs - what you're describing isn't the way brokers work.

Comment: @romkey MQQT Broker doesn't need to subscribe to the topics to listen. Only the client need to subscribe to the topics

Comment: @ShehanSimen   [Bevywise MQTTRoute](https://www.bevywise.com/mqtt-broker/) provides options to build application behind the broker. However we use the Python as the application building layer.  It provides options to store data on the DB and use it by your application.

Comment: @RanjithKumarDiraviyam I am looking for Java Spring boot app

Comment: @ShehanSimen   The default build of the MQTTRoute is an exe. However, we have a Python extension for the message received and We can initialize the spring boot application inside the python interface and also we can pass on the messages received using the same interface. 

Hope this helps. 

Disclaimer:  Giving this suggestion without the complete use case knowledge of the spring boot application you are developing.

Comment: @RanjithKumarDiraviyam your app is a paid app. I only want to use open source software.